# Angular 2 Empty Component Routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am new to Angular 2 and I have a question regarding routing. I have a app.routing file, in which I only want one path.

```
{path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent}
```

But if I run this code I get an error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ''
```

So i decided to just use an empty component on the ' ' path, which works exactly like i wanted.

Routing File:

```
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {SignupComponent} from "./signup/signup.component";
import {EmptyComponent} from "./empty/empty.component";

const appRoutes:Routes = [
    {path: '', component: EmptyComponent},
    {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent}
];

export const appRoutingProviders = [];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

The file with the router-outlet:

```
<header>
    <div class="btn-wrapper">
        <button class="btn-sign-up btn-fancy" routerLink="/signup">Sign Up</button>
        <button class="btn-sign-in btn-ghost btn-fancy">Sign In</button>
    </div>
    <i class="material-icons more">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <div class="overlay" *ngIf="overlay" (click)="close()"></div>
    <div class="tinted"></div>
</header>
```

I just want that the router only routes the SignupComponent on the 'signup' path. Is there another way to do this and eliminate the use of an empty component? I am sorry if this question is poorly written, I am very new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 9):

Just make your empty route redirect to the signup route:

```
const appRoutes:Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'signup', pathMatch: 'full'}, 
    {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent}
];
```

Or if you want the router outlet to be empty until you navigate to `signup`, leave the four totally empty :

```
const appRoutes:Routes = [
    {path: '', children: []}, 
    {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent}
];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I don't want anything to be routed on the path ' '. SignupComponent should only show up on 'signup'.

Comment: Thanks again, but now I get this error: Invalid configuration of route '': one of the following must be provided (component or redirectTo or children or loadChildren)

Comment: Oh really? That worked on a previous beta but perhaps it doesn't work any more, sorry. Which version of angular are you using? 2.0.0 final?

Comment: No problem. Yeah, I am using the 2.0.0 version.

Comment: I am having this same problem in final version, I need to have a totally empty route, but `{path: ''"}` throws an error

Comment: There's a bug in router 3.1.2, try 3.1.1 or 3.2.0-rc. 0

Comment: empty path does not work in @angular/router v3.4.1 "One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren"

Comment: the solution is to add empty children like so, `children: []`

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

If you *know* that there's nothing to be shown in the child router outlet you can actually hide it. Then you won't get the error.

```
<router-outlet *ngIf="hasNoQuestionSelected$ | async"></router-outlet>
```

I feel like this is more technically correct than a 'dummy component', however there are absolutely cases where that is fine and legitimate and probably safer. Even while presenting this as a solution that seems to work it's possible that doing this may add difficult to debug race conditions - which will likely depend on how you determine whether or not to show the outlet.

Curious to hear if people think this is a terrible or legitimate solution.

PS. Don't get confused with Angular's [EmptyOutletComponent](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/components/empty_outlet.ts). This is related but not the same thing, and actually adds a new router-outlet for empty routes.

--

Option 2:

You can have a route that only has a path and no children, component or redirect.

You can still query the `ActivatedRoute` snapshot and traverse down the tree to find the parameters you need - they're still there. But without a `<router-outlet>` the router won't try to actually do anything itself - that's up to you. Or you can still define a component and then based on a condition (eg. screen width) decide whether to show or hide a `router-outlet` to consume it.

Why would I want this you might ask? Sometimes with responsive design for different screen sizes I find myself needing completely different behavior. Sometimes this warrants 'delving' into `snapshot.children[0].routeData` to pull out the URL parameters. I'll then just display the component myself in the main component.

Just adding this as another alternative for certain cases.

```
{
    path: 'contactus',
    component: ContactUsComponent,

    children: [
        {
            path: 'topics',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: '/support/contactus'
        },
        {
            path: ':category',

            children: 
            [
                {
                    path: ':question'
                    // component: ContactUsFormComponent
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { DemoComponent } from './demo.component';

const demoRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: DemoComponent }
];

export const demoRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild( demoRoutes );
```